# How to remove cell from my filtered list?

Tags: swift, xcode

I have a list and I want to click on a line to delete this line.
So I have a tableview. Datas in the tableView come from mysql database (I used this tutorial to access database https://codewithchris.com/iphone-app-connect-to-mysql-database/). I add a UISearchBar to filter the list. All is ok if I don't use the searchbar but if I use it, I can't delete/remove the raw.

I tried to use code for searchbar but I have the error Could not cast value of type 'Swift._ContiguousArrayStorage<*******.*****Model>' (0x1e91fbcc8) to 'NSMutableArray'

```
var feedItems: NSArray = NSArray()  
var filtered*****s: NSArray = NSArray()

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    selected***** = (filtered*****s[indexPath.row] as! *****Model)

    var type***** : Int = 0

    let alertController1 = UIAlertController(title: selected*****.nom*****, message: Constants.choose_type_*****, preferredStyle: .alert)
    alertController1.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: Constants.*******, style: .default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
        self.dataAdd.append((self.idEtablissement,self.selected*****.id*****!,0))
            type***** = 0
        self.registerNew*****(nom*****: self.selected*****.nom*****!, id*****: self.selected*****.id*****!, type*****: type*****)

    }))
    alertController1.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: Constants.*********, style: .default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in                    self.dataAdd.append((self.idEtablissement,self.selected*****.id*****!,1))
            type***** = 1
        self.registerNew*****(nom*****: self.selected*****.nom*****!, id*****: self.selected*****.id*****!, type*****: type*****)

    }))

    self.present(alertController1, animated: true, completion: nil)

    if (isSearch == false){

        let test1 = self.filtered*****s as! NSMutableArray
        test1.removeObject(at: indexPath.row)

        Liste*****.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableView.RowAnimation.automatic)

        self.Liste*****.reloadData()

    } else {

        let test1 = self.filtered*****s as! NSMutableArray
        test1.removeObject(at: indexPath.row)

    }

func searchBar(_ searchList: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    if searchList.text! == "" {
        filtered*****s = feedItems
        isSearch = false
    } else {

        filtered*****s = feedItems.filter { ($0 as! *****Model).nom*****!.lowercased().contains(searchList.text!.lowercased()) } as! [*****Model] as NSArray
        isSearch = true
    }

    self.Liste*****.reloadData()
}

}
```

Do you have any idea about the code for searchbar ? I have to delete the cell in the data but in my case I have two datas : the filtered and the not filtered. I have to remove data from the tableView. I had problem with the number of line before and after which is not the same...

Comment: You redacted your variable and model names with the worst character. Just replace it with Foo or something next time. You're also force unwrapping and force casting everything, that's going to crash eventually.

Comment: @EmilioPelaez what do you mean about "with Foo or something" ?

Comment: `filteredFoos` is readable, `filtered*****s` is not and makes the code a lot harder to scan. Both of them redact your sensitive information.

Comment: OK ! I don't use character * in my code. It's only because I don't want to expose my project to everybody

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll **never** get an `NSMutableArray` in coercion.

Basically don't use `NS(Mutable)..` collection types in Swift at all. Use native types

```
var feedItems = [Model]()
var filtered*****s = [Model]()
```

these arrays are mutable for free. By the way `*****Model` doesn't compile anyway.

Then you can write much *swiftier*

```
if isSearch {
    self.filtered*****s.remove(at: indexPath.row)
} else {
    self.feedItems.remove(at: indexPath.row)
}
tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
```

---

And this syntax is horrible ( I don't mean the ******)

```
filtered*****s = feedItems.filter { ($0 as! *****Model).nom*****!.lowercased().contains(searchList.text!.lowercased()) } as! [*****Model] as NSArray
```

with native `Model` the line can be reduced to

```
filtered*****s = feedItems.filter { $0.nom*****!.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil }
```

---

And never call `reloadData` right after `deleteRows`.

Comment: thank you very much. If I used NS collection types, it comes from the link at the beginning of my problem. I didn't know xcode and swift before this project. During my search this afternoon, I found that NS was not "swifty". I will change now all the NS...

Comment: there is an error... when I use the entired list, my app is crashing saying "invalid number of rows in section 0...' difference between the number or raw before and after the update.